# Most Pure CSS Clock

Tags: css, sass, less

I am learning how to create pure css objects.
In this moment I'm creating an analogic clock.

The question is: what is the mostly pure way to create this clock with the current hour.

I mean... I know how to move the hands, I know a way (with javascript) to display the current hour. But I can't move the hands starting at the current hour.

Was I explicit? What is the best way? (I never used less or sass or another one, but I can give it a try. :) )

Here is my code in codepen: codepen.io/AlexandraCardoso/pen/ZeQdxg

Thanks for your help and sorry about any english error.

Comment: You need javascript to fetch current time. then to start animation, you need an extra wrapper for each hour, minute and second display that you can set on the fly the proper rotation to start from current time. You will need to update transform:rotate on load once for each. Visually, Your animations will start from there ...

Comment: ... quick example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OppvBJ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically changing CSS keyframe values to create a clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316909/dynamically-changing-css-keyframe-values-to-create-a-clock)

Answer (score 2):

To make it as "CSS" as possible you could use CSS Variables – this way you only need to instantiate the clock and let CSS handle the animation

```
//  set current time on load
const now = new Date()
const docStyle = document.documentElement.style;
docStyle.setProperty('--seconds', now.getSeconds());
docStyle.setProperty('--minutes', now.getMinutes());
docStyle.setProperty('--hours',   now.getHours());
```

Here is a simple dummy http://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/pePMzE

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do is this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZZaNY

HTML:

```
.canvas
  .relogio
    #hora
    #minuto
    #segundo
    .centro

  .shadow
    .shadow-inner
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background-color:salmon;
}

.canvas{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 600px; height: 600px;
}

.relogio{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:white;
  width:600px; height:600px;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:25px solid lightsalmon;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#hora{
  z-index:3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid darkgray;
  top: calc(45% - 120px); left: calc(50% - 20px);
  transform-origin: 50% 185%;
transform:rotate(12deg);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#hora:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px; top: 60px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 60px solid salmon;
}

#minuto{
  z-index:2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid lightcoral;
  top: calc(45% - 200px) ; left: calc(50% - 20px);
  transform-origin: 50% 190%;
transform: rotate(6deg);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#minuto:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px; top: 100px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid lightcoral;
}

#segundo{
  z-index:1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px; height: 45%;
  background-color:darkgray;
  top:5%; left: calc(50% - 1px);
  transform:rotate(1deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.centro {
  z-index:4;
  height: 5%;
  width: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: salmon;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.shadow{
  z-index:-1;
  position:absolute;
  width:600px; height:600px;
  transform:translate(0%, 50%);
}
.shadow-inner{
  width:600px; height:600px;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  background: black;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(gray,transparent); 
  background: -o-linear-gradient(gray,transparent); 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(gray,transparent); 
  background: linear-gradient(gray,transparent); 
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var h = d.getHours();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
if(h>12){h=h-12;}
    var secAngle = s*6;
  var minAngle = m*6;
  var hourAngle = h*30;


  var segundos = document.getElementById('segundo').style.transform = "rotate(" + secAngle + "deg)";
  var minutos = document.getElementById("minuto").style.transform = "rotate(" + minAngle + "deg)";
    var horas = document.getElementById('hora').style.transform = "rotate(" + hourAngle + "deg)";
}
window.onload=function(){
myFunction();
setInterval(myFunction,1000);
}
$(document).ready(myFunction());
```